# Invalid conversion of child class pointer

Tags: c++, itk

In the following code:

```
#include "itkImage.h"
#include "itkImageRegionIterator.h"

struct CustomImageBase
{
  virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

template <typename TPixel>
struct CustomImage : public itk::Image<TPixel, 2>, public CustomImageBase
{
  void DoSomething()
  {
    itk::Index<2> index;
    index.Fill(0);
    std::cout << this->GetPixel(index);
  }
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
  std::vector<CustomImageBase*> images;

  CustomImage<float>* floatImage = CustomImage<float>::New().GetPointer();
  CustomImage<int>* intImage = CustomImage<int>::New().GetPointer();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the error: invalid convsion from itk::Image* to CustomImage*

Note that this works fine:

```
itk::Image<float>* testFloatImage = itk::Image<float>::New().GetPointer();
```

Since CustomImage inherits from itk::Image, I don't understand the problem?

Comment: Does itk require special allocation handling or why are you not just using `new CustomImage<float>`?

Comment: Georg, yes unfortunately. The constructors are private so you have to use New().

Comment: Ah, then inheriting from them won't work, so you need to use containment instead of inheritance. Unless they offer some alternative like a factory where you can register your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` derives from `A`, you cannot convert `A*` to `B*`. If `C` also derives from `A`, and your `A*` really points to a `C` object instead of a `B` object, what would happen if you *pretend* it is a `B`? The conversion is unsafe. In your case, *you* know that `GetPointer()` will always return a `CustomImage<T>`. The compiler does not know that. You can tell it by using a cast:

```
CustomImage<float>* floatImage = static_cast<CustomImage<float>*>(CustomImage<float>::New().GetPointer());
```

**Edit**: this is precisely why the conversion is unsafe: after reading the comments on your question, **I don't believe `CustomImage<float>::New().GetPointer()` really points to a `CustomImage`**, and if not, the cast would simply turn compiler errors into runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

> Since CustomImage inherits from itk::Image, I don't understand the problem?

Since `CustomImage` inherits from `itk::Image`, this means that `CustomImage*` can be implicitly converted to `itk::Image*`. However, the compiler is complaining about the **opposite** conversion:

> invalid convesion **from** `itk::Image*` **to** `CustomImage*`

This requires an explicit type cast.

I can't compile your code since I don't have the pre-requisites, and you don't say which line of the code the compiler doesn't like, so it's hard to provide further help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this was allowed. Now consider the following:

```
struct yet_another_image : public itk::Image<TPixel, 2> {
}

yet_another_image img;
itk::Image<TPixel, 2>* ptr = &img; // ok
CustomImage* bad = ptr; // oops!
```

You can safely convert from a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to base class, but you can't safely convert the other way around, because you don't know if the object pointed to has the correct type.